# Vuetify Treeview - How to select a previuos activated node

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a problem using the treeview component of vuetify:
when a user selects a tree node, then a dialog appears asking for confirmation of activation of the selected node;
if the user cancels the selection then the tree returns to the previously opened node, otherwise it opens the new selected node.

How can I get this result?

Here are my results:

- When I select a node of the tree, making the confirmation dialogue appear, the tree has already selected the new node without waiting for the confirmation of the dialogue;
- When I cancel the selection of the node, through the dialog, the tree continues to show as active node the one subject to the last choice and not the one prior to the choice

Perhaps a solution is to invoke, programmatically, the treeview component event called 'update:active' with the desired node descriptor as an argument...
but is it possible to trigger vuetify events programmatically?

And if so, how is it done?

Comment: Please mention the Vue and Vuetify version.

Comment: Vuetify v2.6.14;  Vue v2.6.12

Comment: I am not sure if this can be done because all events of treeview return an array of modified items that are of no use to propagate or prevent the clicking event further. :(